# Cannot cast String to Integer

Tags: java, android

I know this has been asked before.... I'm newbie to Java as well to Android.

One of my friend developing an app and he's using MPAndroidChartLibrary.

The code works fine on local server. Not from the PUBLIC server.

Here's the code

```
 private List<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    List<BarDataSet> dataSets;
    List<BarEntry> resolvedBarEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    List<Integer> listKey = Lists.newArrayList(resolveSerMap.keySet());
    Collections.sort(listKey);
    for (Integer key : listKey) {
        BarEntry resolvedBar = new BarEntry(resolveSerMap.get(key), key);
        resolvedBarEntries.add(resolvedBar);
    }
    List<BarEntry> closedBarEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    for (Integer key : listKey) {
        BarEntry closedBar = new BarEntry(closeSerMap.get(key), key);
        closedBarEntries.add(closedBar);
    }
    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(resolvedBarEntries,
            getResources().getString(R.string.Resolved));
    //barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS);

    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(closedBarEntries,
            getResources().getString(R.string.Closed));
    //barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
    dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
    return dataSets;
}
```

This is always ends in exception as
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
            at com.example.user.getDataSet(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.user.promiseMethod(Unknown Source)
            at com.gaurage.util.RestUtil$3.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.h.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Please tell me where should i look deeply..Initially i never faced an error from this class.

Comment: What does this returns "resolveSerMap.keySet()" String or Integer?

Comment: Let me debug that app one more time and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: When i point the debug over there is shows as

listkey: size =12 resolverMap: size=12

Comment: Have you tried to clean, rebuild and run?

Comment: Yes i did, it seems the error gone....
//barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS); 
the above code line seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error probably is in:

`List<Integer> listKey = Lists.newArrayList(resolveSerMap.keySet());`

Are the keys Integers? or Strings?

Comment: listkey: size =12 resolverMap: size=12 returns integers only